# Why does a query joining several views take 10x as long as running the views individually?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, view

I need some help optimising a query which is looks simple of the face of it, but is blowing up my DB.

The objective is to produce an output file to update a website, but creating a single view (View_1) which combines the central index table (list_1) with the results of several other views (View_2_1 through View_2_8). My stored procedure is design to run View_1, select the records which need to be updated and drop them into a static table where they can picked up by an automated process (which only needs to run 1 line of code and will be well within the timeout limit).

- After adding all suggested missing indexes to target tables, when I
  run View 2_1 through View 2_8 individually they take between 3” and
  39” to resolve.
- When I run the code for View 1 in isolation it takes
  21 mins.
- When I ran the stored procedure to run view 1 this morning, it
  took over an hour!

Can anyone see anything obvious in the below that may be adding to the query cost?

**View 1 code:**
Edit: `Select distinct` appears to be the issue here. Objective is to pick up a unique row for every unique value in the "article" column. Those values should only appear once in each table and view.

```
select distinct article, publisher, /*[list required columns 1 -40 from each table and view, correcting null values to ‘-’ where required.]*/
from list_1 as l1
left join list_2 as l2 on
l1.publisher=l2.publisher
left join view_2_1 as v21 on
l1.article=v21.article
left join view_2_2 as v22
l1.article=v22.article
left join view_2_3 as v23
l1.article=v23.article
left join view_2_4 as v24
l1.article=v24.article
left join view_2_5 as v25
l1.article=v25.article
left join view_2_6 as v26
l1.article=v26.article
left join view_2_7 as v27
l1.article=v27.article
left join view_2_8 as v28
l1.article=v28.article
```

The stored procedure is

```
drop table if exists todays_export_articles;
select *
into todays_export_articles
from import_procedure  /* ie code above */
/* Select latest and discard invalid records */
where [type]='article' and [status]='pending' and important_column_1 is not null and important_column_2 is not null and important_column_3 is not null;
update list_1
set [status]='published'
from todays_export_articles as ta inner join list_1 as l1
on ta.article=l1.article
```

Comment: *"which is looks simple of the face of it"* This query looks "simple", but the definition of those `VIEW`s could be far from simple. Do you *really* have views called `view_2_2` as well? I really recommend giving them useful and meaningful names.

Comment: As for the question, when asking for query tuning advice, you should really include the DDL for the objects involved, along with their indexes, and the query plan in a consumable format (such as by using [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/). At least start with the query plan, and they *might* indicate to us that you have some poorly written views.

Comment: One note, however: having a `DISTINCT` on this query, where you *imply* there you are asking for 40 columns from every view (for a total of 362 total columns?!) is going to be ***AWFUL*** for performance. Do you *really* need that `DISTINCT`?

Comment: One way to look at it is that views are representations of other queries. So if I `select *` from a view, I'm basically running a query that could have functions, numerous joins, etc. which add to the "cost" (in terms of resources) needed to execute. By joining a bunch of views, you're joining data in a very roundabout way, especially with a bunch of LEFT joins. I'm making a couple assumptions here, but that's a straight-forward way to look at it.

Comment: @larnu What do you mean by *that distinct*??? I don't understand. The only column I need distinct is article - ie one entry per article. 40 columns in total.

Comment: *"What do you mean by that distinct???"* The one right at the start of your query, it's literally the second word, @smallnorthumbrianvillage . `SELECT DISTINCT ....`

Comment: @larnu no, I mean I don't understand, as in "please explain a little more why this would be an issue". I only learned sql 6 months ago and no explanation is too simple for me.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT` means that the `SELECT` needs to return a `DISTINCT` result set. If you have 362 columns, then all those 362 columns must be checked to see if that version of the data doesn't appear again in the entire result set, @smallnorthumbrianvillage . This normally means that, in the background, SQL Server will need to sort the entire data set, by **every** column and then when there are 2 or more rows that are identical, "merge" them into a single one.

Comment: `DISTINCT` means distinct over every column, I suspect that is not what was intended rather you need `GROUP BY`, rarely do I see `DISTINCT` used where it is supposed to be. Begs the question why are you joining so many times on a column called `article`, you probably need conditional aggregation instead. We have no idea as you have given us almost no info to work with other than part of what is quite clearly a poorly written query

Comment: article is the unique reference column. I initially tried using ´Group by´ but kept getting "Column 1 is Not valid in select list...". After seeing that for 8+ columns, I thought ´distinct´ must be the better method.

Comment: Nesting views, which may in turn use other views, is a recipe for poor performance for a multitude of reasons. Sometimes the easiest workaround is to use temp tables to materialize each result set and then use these in the final query.

Comment: Thanks @larnu @Stu @Charlieface @jw11432 . I thought CharlieFace's comment "poorly written" was a bit harsh at the time, but having taken Stu's advice and re-written this as temporary tables, I found a fair few joins that made sense for isolated views, but just added to the workload in a nested query. I also took out the `distinct`. End result, a slow but consistently resolving query and a lesson learned.